# Difference between Kompose and compose-on-kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, migration, cloud

I am evaluating a migration of an application working with docker-compose to Kubernates and came across two solutions: Kompose and compose-on-kubernetes.

I'd like to know their differences in terms of functionality/ease of use to make decision of which one is more suited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both product provide a migration path from docker-compose to Kubernetes, but they do it in a slightly different way.

- Compose on Kubernetes runs within your Kubernetes cluster and allows you to deploy your compose setup unchanged on the Kubernetes cluster.
- Kompose translates your docker-compose files to a bunch of Kubernetes resources.

Compose is a good solution if you want to continue running using docker-compose in parallel to deploying on Kubernetes and so plan to keep the docker-compose format maintained.

If you're migrating completely to Kubernetes and don't plan to continue working with docker-compose, it's probably better to complete the migration using Kompose and use that as the starting point for maintaining the configuration directly as Kubernetes resources.

Comment: Thanks @intellectonica for all clarification. Just a side question.. I tried Kompose and it generated one Deployment for each of my images. Is this a best practice? From what I've read a Pod (instance of a Deployment) is a set of containers sharing the same lifecicle. When I docker-compose up, all containers share that lifecicle so it seems a little odd to me. PS.: my application is a chatbot, which is a pipeline of microservices with different text processing functions.

Comment: It's hard for Kompose to deduce from docker-compose.yaml what is the best layout for your application, so the best it can do is generate one deployment per service. Whether you want them all to be in the same pod or separate, depends on how you want to scale (if at all). If you only need one instance of each component you can indeed group them together, but if you see an option to have multiple instances of a component you might want to deploy it separately.